# AppCode targeted device families not valid (iPad iOS 8.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios8, appcode

I keep getting this error in AppCode, but usually it runs just fine with Xcode:

> Error:xcodebuild: error: The run destination iPad Mini is not valid
>   for Running the scheme 'Appname'.
>  Error:iPad Mini doesn't match any of
>   Appname.app's targeted device families. You can expand Appname.app's
>   targeted device families to support iPad Mini. 
> Error:Build failed with
>   2 errors and 0 warnings in 7 sec 
> Note:Building for 2 architectures.
>   Double click to set 'ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES' to speed up compilation.

**Target sdk is 7.1 in AppCode 3.0.6 (Xcode 6.1)**
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 2 (iPad)
VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s i386 arm64
Architectures = Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)

I have the problem with both an iPad Mini with iOS 8.1 and a iPad 4 with iOS 7.1.

Any idea why it will not work from AppCode?

Comment: I had that as well.Did you try EAP 3.1? Fixed it for me

Comment: Yes - that fixes it. Thanks - please make an answer with it @brainray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that as well: Xcode builds fine, Appcode does not. There is no evident reason for that - the target etc looks fine. It seems to be a bug in AppCode 3.0.6 that seems to be fixed in the 3.1 EAP version. With 3.1 the project builds fine here.

Comment: I'm using AppCode 3.1.2 and i'm getting this problem. Sometimes it works but most the time it doesn't. I don't like having to go to Xcode just to run the app :-(

Comment: Are you sure that you have assigned the right version of Xcode in Appcode? Prefs->Tools->Xcode

Comment: Yeah, I only have one version of Xcode on my machine. 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Answer (score 3):

According to JetBrains, it's a problem with the `xcodebuild` tool in Xcode 6 rather than being an issue with AppCode. Hopefully something Apple will fix soon!

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11204

Comment: When my Xcode 6.3 is building for "Universal" than AppCode 3.1.5 is building and running on my iPad. When Xcode is building for iPad only than the error is occuring: "Error:xcodebuild: error: The run destination ... is not valid for Running the scheme..."

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem as well in Appcode. If you set "Targeted Device Family" in Appcode's target to "1,2" (iPhone and iPad), it worked here.

Comment: This is the workaround suggested in AppCode OC-11204 while we are waiting for a bug fix from Apple. Go to Xcode change targeted device family to universal, just ignore the other devices and then you can build in AppCode.

Answer (score 2):

Go To Build Settings -> 
in search bar, search "targeted"

change in Universal

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 14.1 now its iPhone, iPad option instead of Universal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check Development info like development target, Device and match with the simulator device.